# vscode "lint ignore" for task output (languages that are not in-built into vscode - tasks.json/settings.json?)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

## scenario

Using vscode with COBOL and a task to compile the sources + a defined problemMatcher does:

- execute the task correctly (all output shown in the Terminal pane)
- parses errors and warnings correctly showing them in the Problems pane

## issue

Some warnings are "unwanted" and decided to be ignored (not by the compiler, so they will still be raised and seen in the terminal), but they should not be shown in the Problems pane.

Moving the mouse over the error says "add a lint comment to ignore the warning, but clicking on it does not change the code (which I *guess* is what it is intended to do).

[image: Problems pane with a nice suggestion]

## question

Is there an option to define rules to ignore warnings where the linter is not known to vscode (actually the "linter" is the problemMatcher defined in tasks.json), likely settings.json/tasks.json?

If nothing can be done directly it *may* be possible to define a problem-matcher to say "ignore"? If yes - how?
If that is still not possible then I'd define a fixed pattern to have these warnings matched as info - but I'd like to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been raised with the extension author and an answer to the specific questions can be found @ https://github.com/spgennard/vscode_cobol/issues/216.

Most important:

> The issue [...] observed was related to [a bug:] the linter being triggered for non-linter issues and this was resolved a months ago [in the extension]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative lookahead to the problemmatcher:

`(?!.*(?:sometextYouDontWant|otherTextNotWanted))here_the_original_regex`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would be needed to be added in every problem matcher that would otherwise match though, so it may not be appropriate - but at least it is possible to use this as a work around. 
A similar thing would be a negative filter (doesn't change anything to the numbers though, so this workaround is better).